# html: Can I stop a gif? (Looking for ways that can accomplish same effect as "stop" a gif)

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I am working on a code that is an interactive door. It opens and closes based on mouseclick. 
What I'm trying to realize is to make the gif on the door turns still when it is closed --
(I guess I should make another still image of the gif and when the mouse clicks on the door for even number times, the gif turns to the still image? It's just my guess, I really don't know much about coding) My code is as below:

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@0.10.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/sketch.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/openDoor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <div class="perspective" onclick="openDoor(this)">
            <div class="thumb">
            </div>
        </div>       
  <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Door</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<body>
</html>
```

The js:

```
function openDoor(field) {
    var y = $(field).find(".thumb");
    var x = y.attr("class");
    if (y.hasClass("thumbOpened")) {
        y.removeClass("thumbOpened");
    }
    else {
        $(".thumb").removeClass("thumbOpened");
        y.addClass("thumbOpened");
    }
}
```

The css:

```
body
{
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

.container
{
            margin:0 auto;
            width:90%;
}
.perspective
{
   background: url("http://dc428.4shared.com/img/QWu4ziBq/s3/doorBorder.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            position: relative;
            display: inline;
            float: left;
            height: 274px;
            width: 147px;
            margin: 40px;
            margin-left: 400px;
            -webkit-perspective: 450;
            border-radius: 3px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .thumb
        {
            background: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/l41m4IRJqzgtFQ4O4/giphy.gif");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;

            width: 147px;
            height: 274px;
            position: relative;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border-radius: 3px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) inset;
            transition: 1s transform linear;
            transform-origin: left;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .thumbOpened
        {
            transform: rotateY(-90deg);
            transform-origin: 8px;
            transition: .5s linear;
        }

.alert {
padding: 8px 35px 8px 14px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
background-color: #fcf8e3;
border: 1px solid #fbeed5;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
  color: #000;

    transform-origin: left;
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  opacity:0;
  animation-name: go;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  width:350px;
}
@keyframes go {
  100%{
    opacity:1;
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to stop the animation of a gif? I appreciate any help!

Comment: no, an image is an image and it can't be directly manipulated

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to figure out other ways to accomplish that